# Why do elements need to be floated right before left when in the same container with a centred element?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I had a problem with a right floated element not staying on the same horizontal alignment as a left floated element and a centred element. The right floated element was floating right, but sitting below the horizontal line the others were on.

When floating elements (for example one left, one centred and one right) in the same div, the right element needs to stack before the left element.

**Example:**

```
<div id=container>
    <div id="float-right"></div>
    <div id="margin-auto"></div>
    <div id="float-left"></div>
</div>
```

If I have only two elements, one left and one right they sit horizontally as below.

**See example**: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mSXX6/)

When I add a central element the right element moves down.

**See example**: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mSXX6/1/)

What is happening here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will provide you with a simple example here, let's assume that you are not assigning the middle `div` any `width` so see what it will be actually doing

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mSXX6/3/)

```
<div style="width:100%">
   <div style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:red;float:left;border: 3px solid #000;"></div>
   <div style="height:20px;background-color:red;margin:0 auto auto;border: 3px solid #000;"></div>   
   <div style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:red;float:right;border: 3px solid #000;"></div>
</div>
```

Why this happens?

`div` is a `block-level` element, it takes up the entire horizontal space on the page, if you know, when you `float` any element either `left` or `right` it won't take `100%` anymore and it will take only the space assigned by using width, or the content it holds, so in this case, `left floated` `div` will take `20px` width leaving other space unused. Now you have another `div` which IS NOT FLOATED but it will take the rest of the available horizontal space, making your `right floated` `div` element to push down.

So what to do in order to solve this?

You need to `float` all the `div` to the left, or it may be enough if you make the `middle` `div` `float` to the left or to the right. Now I am aware that you want to have 2 `div`, 1 floated to left and other to right, but this is not the right way to do that, if you want, you can wrap the elements inside a container `div`, or what you can use is `position: absolute;` to set the elements right.

---

In order to show you how block level elements work, I will share you another example here..

Assume that you are having a `div` nested inside a `p` tag (This is invalid so please never use this in real world, this is just for demonstration purpose), and give some width to the `div` element and see how it renders your text.

```
<p>Hello World, I don't want the <div>text to</div> break</p>

div {
    width: 40px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mSXX6/4/)

Though you provide the `width` to block level element, it will still break the paragraph.

---

From [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)

> By default, block-level elements are formatted differently than inline
>   elements. Generally, block-level elements begin on new lines, inline
>   elements do not.

Comment: @Aaron make it `inline-block` and see how it behaves, I already mentioned that whether you provide a block level element width or not, it won't matter, it will take the rest of the space, breaking the rest to other line, I will show you 1 more example.

Comment: You don't need to do any of that. Just put the floats above the block level element and you get what you want.

Comment: He doesn't need to if he wants it in the middle. Nor does he need inline-block. See: http://jsfiddle.net/k3xK8/

Comment: @ToddBerman because you are moving the markup, you are using a block level element after floated elements... and I've also added your solution in my answer :)

Comment: Yes, that is the right way to do what is being attempted, not absolute positioning.

Comment: @ToddBerman Even absolute positioning will be fine here, but wait, I again removed, you are missing something here, check this out :) http://jsfiddle.net/mSXX6/5/

Comment: @ToddBerman unless you don't float the middle one to left, it will actually render from extreme left thus hiding the 20px text, than you need to use margins, so in short, it is just dirty

Comment: Not sure what you think I am missing. If you want something to be smaller than its container and centered horizontally, you use an auto margin, that is how HTML works.

In both fiddles (yours and mine) you are getting 100% expected behavior that works even in older browsers (unlike inline-block) and without absolute positioning (which is always a questionable thing to use).

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the way elements are floated according to the HTML spec. Elements are floated horizontally from left to right. Any floated element will appear as far left as it possibly can.

Since `div` is a block level element, it will push everything down on the right hand side, but stack against anything on the left.

In your example, you can not see it, but the floated, or centre, `div` extends all the way out to the edge of the page as demonstrated by @Mr. Alien's fiddle.

You can read more about this in the spec:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing

Answer (score 1):

`div` is a block level element, it is making your right `div` push down as it is not floated, either on left or on the right side, and hence it pushes your other `div` below.

If you float that too, it will make the rest of the space on other side empty, thus it will allow the right floated `div` to sit beside the middle `div`

http://jsfiddle.net/mSXX6/2/

Comment: I was wondering why it doesn't also push the left element down?

Comment: @Aaron because your left element is floated to the left, and than you render the other `div` which is not floated, so it will affect the elements rendered after the `div` which is not floated

Answer (score 0):

If you put both floats above the non-floated div, you will get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for the logic as to what is happening in my example

Comment: Its CSS floats, there is no logic! :)

Comment: There's a bit of logic as you can see from above answers. Thanks all the same :)

Comment: Yeah, my comment was a joke. Mohamad has the right answer, with links to the spec you should read to understand how floats work. You don't need to use inline-block (nor will it work on old browsers).